# Add automatic transition to Flex states

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, mxml

[State transitions](http://www.artima.com/articles/state_transitions_in_flex_4.html) in [flex](http://www.artima.com/articles/flex_4_states.html) are very helpful. Is it possible to add an automatic state transition between state A and state B in case there is no user response for 5 mins in state A or pop-up an alert?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason to not just use a timer in stateA and then set currentState = "stateB" if the timer completes with no user interaction?

Comment: I want to add a global timer to change from any state A to B or A to c based on no user interaction. How can I use it in a mxml flex4 app..any code snippet?